# Best way to switch languages in the software or website?

Tags: localization, internationalization

I want to know the best programming technique to switch languages in the software or website. So anyone can give me some suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: The best is to detect preferred Locale and ***not switching*** at all. User already set his/her preference either in Operating System or in the Web Browser (so-called Accept Languages), why you want to override this choice?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard. But I used the following technique in websites.

1. Put all the visible strings (eg. "file", "menu", "contact us") in a file or database. It can be xml, json or any format that you easily parse later. Make sure all the data is saved in different directory/db tables according to locale/language.
2. Wrap all the strings with a function or static class method. Every time they are displayed they'll go through some processing.
3. When you first load the software or web determine the locale or language that user wants to use.
4. According to users choice select the string source. database, filepath etc. For e.g. if user want to see strings in `en_GB` locale, find  strings in en_GB folder or in `lang_en_GB` table. Naming format is in your hand.
5. Now each time the function or static class method is called find strings in the source you selected on *Step 4*.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the language you are using. Many have built in support for it. In android for example what you do is store all strings into an xml file that is named based on the region. And the operating system will automatically use the appropriate resources based on the phones region.

Look into what support your language/platform includes. You will want to externalize all your string constants such as "Press the menu button" into an external file. Then just get this file translated to each language you want to support, and use the OS to automatically use the correct resource file. Or if the platform/OS does not support such a thing write some code to determine which resource file to use yourself.